# How to run @beforeclass @test and @Afterclass cases in a loop using TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

In

```
@beforeclass 
login(){
open browser
login();
}

@test
test1(){

Action 1;
}

@test
test2(){

Action 2;
}

@afterclass
logout(){
}
```

I need to run the above set in a loop. For eg, Need to login with one Id run all my @test cases and logout and in loop need to login again with diff Id and need to perform same operation. 
How can i do this using selenium.
Kindly suggest me some Idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use @BeforeMethod instead of using any loops. It will reset mocks before every new test method

Answer (score 0):

I am not so much familiar with Selenium and TestNG, but, normally in unit tets, you cannot guarantee order in which the @Test methods will run.

Therefore just have one @Test annotation, and manually run the methods you want, in the order you want.

So for instance

```
@Test
public void test() {
   login("username"); 
   test1();
   test2();
   test3();
   logout("username");       
   login("newusername"); 
   test1();
   test2();
   test3();
   logout("newusername");       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` instead `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotation

> `@BeforeMethod` - The annotated method will be run before each test
>   method.
>
> `@AfterMethod` - The annotated method will be run after each test
>   method.

```
@BeforeMethod
public void driverSetup()
{
    // Driver setup code
}
@Test
public void loginTest1()
{
    // User Login Code
}
@Test
public void loginTest2()
{
    // User Login Code
}
@AfterMethod
public void driverSetup()
{
    // Driver Closeup code
}
```

Look into some basic tutorials https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_basic_annotations.htm

Answer (score 0):

i would rather do it with testng.xml file. it help you in understanding report

**Java Code**

```
public class demo {

    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters({ "username", "password" })
    public void login(String username, String password){
        System.out.print("login with "+username+" "+password);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        System.out.print("test1");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        System.out.print("test2");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void logout(){
        System.out.print("logout");
    }
}
```

**TestNG.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Regression" >
    <test name="AdminUser">
        <parameter name="username" value="gaurnag"/>
        <parameter name="password" value="shah" />
        <classes>
            <class name="demo"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="StandardUser">
        <parameter name="username" value="standard"/>
        <parameter name="password" value="shah" />
        <classes>
            <class name="demo"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @DataProvider for this. Please read it from
[official site](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

```
@BeforeClass
public void startbrowser(){
open browser
}

@Test(dataProvider="getData")
public void login(String username, String password){

enter_username(username);
enter_password(password);
click_on_submit

logout

}

@AfterClass
public void stop_browser(){

}
@DataProvider
public Object[][] getData()
{

Object[][] data = new Object[2][2];

// 1st row
data[0][0] ="user1";
data[0][1] = "test123";

// 2nd row
data[1][0] ="user2";
data[1][1] = "test123";

return data;
}
```